# Jquery Toggle slide of Child Element

Tags: jquery, html, toggle, parent-child, slide

I'm trying to create a list of titles that when clicked will show the information underneath them and then when clicked again will hide that element.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('.content').hide();

        $(".reveal-more").click(function() {
            $(".content", this).slideDown("slow");
            $(".content", this).addClass("open-information");
            $(".reveal-more h3").addClass("open-container");

        });

        $(".reveal-more").click(function() {

            $(".content").hide();
        });

});
```

and here is my HTML:

```
<div class="reveal-more ">
    <h3 >Party Wall Act</h3>
    <div class="content">
             Lorem Ipsum .....
            </div>
</div>
```

When I click the title. the content slides down but it wont slide back up when I click it again. Can anyone help?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Sorry, Edited it and added in :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `toggle()` and `toggleClass()`;

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.content').hide();

    $(".reveal-more").click(function() {
        $(".content", this).toggle("slow");
        $(".content", this).toggleClass("open-information");
        $(".reveal-more h3").toggleClass("open-container");

    });
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/eSV34/)

Comment: Thank you very much. I was also not aware that I could use toggle on the slideDown. This works a treat :)

Comment: just another suggestion.. this is more simple and easier to use: http://jsfiddle.net/BerkerYuceer/C8sCU/

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a condition in the click-event, wheter to show/hide the content. Right now you are binding the click-event *two* times, where the last one overrides the previous.
You shall alter your code to something like this:

```
$(".reveal-more").click(function() {
    if ($(".content", this).hasClass('open-information')){
        // It is visible, then hide it
        $(".content", this).removeClass("open-information").slideUp("slow");
        $("h3", this).removeClass("open-container");
    } else {
        // Show it, as you previously did
        $(".content", this).addClass("open-information").slideDown("slow");
        $("h3", this).addClass("open-container");
    }
});
```